# File open inconsistency

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using code to open all the files in a folder that start with a particular prefix:

```
folder = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Exception Reports\"
pref = "blah blah prefix"
file = pref & "*.xls"
exPath = folder & file
filename = Dir(exPath)

Do While filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (filename)
    ...
    Workbooks(filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
    filename = Dir()
Loop
```

The first time I run the code after opening the macro, I get "Sorry we couldn't find -filename-. Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?" But the -filename- it prints is the one I want it to open, and all I have specified is the prefix I want and the file extension, so it would seem to me like it's finding it just fine if it knows the full file name. Also if I put in a message box between declaring the filename variable and starting the Do While loop, the message box prints the correct filename that I want it to open.

If I save a new file into the folder and name it something like "AA.xls", and then just have the program loop through the folder (rather than specifying the prefix), and then go back and specify the prefix, it works just fine, and continues to work until I close the program and reopen, where the process starts all over. However, this process only works if I save a new file to that folder. If I try to leave the "AA.xls" file in the folder, I get the same error with that file that I get with the others.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: It sounds to me like that is not your own profile folder and you may be running into permissions issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CMD approach and see if you get the same problem, if you do then it's more than likely a permissions issue:

```
Sub SO()

Const folder    As String = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Exception Reports\"
Const pref      As String = "blah blah prefix"
Dim file        As String
Dim exPath      As String
Dim fileName    As Variant

file = pref & "*.xls": exPath = folder & file

For Each fileName In _
    Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & exPath & """ /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

    Workbooks.Open CStr(folder & fileName)
        '// Do code here
    Workbooks(fileName).Close False

Next fileName

End Sub
```

Comment: That works, thanks!

Can you explain what you're doing in the "Filter" line?

Comment: Sure, the `WScript.Shell` object is creating the output (list of files in this case). The `Split()` creates an array from this output, using `vbCrLf` (carriage return & line feed) as the delimiter. Finally, the `Filter()` method filters each item in the array based on it containing a full stop (which a file path will have because of the extention). The reason for filtering is that the `Split()` method leaves a null string as the final item in the array which would cause an error, so we are filtering out this null string and looping through the rest. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: It does. My only outstanding question would be what the " /B /A:-D" portion does.

Comment: These are 'switches' used as part of the command line argument to specify things about the output we require. `/B` means `Basic` which ensures we only get the filename (and doesn't include ad-hoc information in the returned text). `/A:` is the `Attribute` switch and takes various arguments, in this case I've used the `-D` or `Directory` switch with a proceeding `-` which tells CMD **not** to include and directory paths (this is actually redundant here as we aren't checking subfolders so it shouldn't find any directories anyway)